# Why in CSS does '!' in have the opposite meaning to its use in C-based languages?

Tags: css, operators, language-design

For example, in JavaScript, `!important` means 'not important'. In CSS, it means 'this is important'.

Are there languages other than CSS where an exclamation mark is used for affirmation rather than negation? Why was the '!' chosen in CSS?

EDIT

I don't know if it's a coincidence, but `!` is the earliest non-system and non-whitespace character in the ASCII table (at #32). In terms of parsing, would that make it quicker?

Comment: I think it was just to get people's attention.

Comment: `Are there languages other than CSS where an exclamation mark is used for affirmation rather than negation?` -- How about natural languages? ;)

Comment: the obvious candidate for another language using ! for affirmation is natural language!

Comment: Why do JavaScript style comments (`//`) not work in CSS? You could create a whole wiki entry of stuff like this.

Comment: Good question. But in CSS, there are more characters that have odd meanings. Take `>` for instance, that means "greater than" in every other computer language. Or what about `-`, which means subtraction everywhere else, but is just a part of a name in CSS. I don't think you'll get a real answer, only "it was chosen because it happened to be available".

Comment: It's notable that a lot of languages don't use `!` for "not" because it's confusing. For example, Python's not operator is `not`.

Comment: Why does CSS not have an equivalent of malloc?

Comment: Did one of the posts answer your question? If so, could you accept it? Thanks! (see [How do I ask a question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask))

Comment: More to the point, are there languages other than the C family and Java where ! means negation?

Comment: @EJP Many databases accept `!=` as alternative to `<>` as their *not equal* operator.

Comment: Based on the meaning in natural languages, I would rather turn it around and ask why does it mean "not" in other programming languages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is more of an escape character than it is an operator. It is part of `important`, rather than a separate piece (e.g. in JavaScript I'd see this as `!` and `somevar`, whereas in CSS I see this as `!important`). So, it isn't so much *affirmation* as you put it; it just so happens to be the character they chose to throw in front of the keyword `important`.

Also, in non-programming languages, `!` is often used to draw attention to something, although it is often accompanied by some other sort of shape/symbol as well (e.g. ⚠), and this is likely the reason *why* `!` was chosen. It may be helpful to see it as `important!` or `¡important!` (`!important` is just easier to parse and type than the alternatives).

***Edit:** As noted by @mike-samuel: "The [lexical scanner](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) section of the CSS2.1 grammar spec lists `!important` as a single token (`"!"({w}|{comment})*{I}{M}{P}{O}{R}{T}{A}{N}{T}   {return IMPORTANT_SYM;}`) although it does allow whitespace and comments between the `!` and `important`."*

Comment: Quite right.  The [lexical grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) lists `!important` as a single token (`"!"({w}|{comment})*{I}{M}{P}{O}{R}{T}{A}{N}{T} {return IMPORTANT_SYM;}`) although it does allow whitespace and comments between the `'!'` and the `'i'`.

Comment: That does sound like a good explanation. Can any parsing experts confirm that `!important` is easier to parse than `important!`?

Comment: @Blowski, If you had `!` at the end, you'd have to look ahead for the `!` so you can distinguish `important` the identifier from `important!`.  Comment&space tokens can be arbitrarily long so you have to be prepared to consume an arbitrary number of characters after the special identifier `important` but this isn't really a problem in hand-rolled parsers because comments are ignored.  For Yacc, `important!` would be a non-lexical production.  This is a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks, that clears that up. Different question - `|important` would be no more expensive than `!important`, even though `|` is at the end of the ASCII table? Is that right?

Comment: @Blowski, if you look at the SpiderMonkey source code file `jsscan.cpp` you'll see a table `static const uint8 firstCharKinds[]` which is fast lookup table that lets the lexer classify tokens by first byte.  A very small hand-rolled scanner that used this technique might have to have a larger table if you use `|` but I doubt it would affect anything in practice.  Memory constrained devices don't parse CSS.

Comment: @Blowski, yeah, no problem. I ended up deleting my comment because Mike went into more specific detail on the subject (less confusion without mine there).

Answer (score 5):

! is an exclamation mark, so in itself it states that something is important. So I'd rather say it's odd that (other) programming languages use ! as a negator.

In HTML ! is part of a declaration (like `<!-- -->` to declare a comment and `<!DOCTYPE ..>` to declare a doc type), so it has another meaning there.

But then again, CSS is not a programming language at all..

And even amongst programming languages there are differences. And that makes sense., if they were all the same, it would be only one language. :D

Comment: On the other hand, CSS does have C-like structures, like the `{` and `}` to delimit blocks, `;` to end a style, etc. AND it does have a `NOT` operator! So the OP's question does make sense.

Comment: ++1: Completely agree, especially about the fact it's not a programming language.

Comment: @MrLister, hmm, I should have drank more caffeine this morning. Apologies on that--deleting comment.

Comment: @MrLister CSS also uses alphabetic characters, just like natural language, but still it doesn't surprise anyone that it terminates its statements with a `;` instead of a `.`. :)

Comment: Technically, the use of ! in HTML isn't about commenting. Only the -- part does that (like comments in SQL). The <! means "markup declaration" (so that -- will be interpreted as comment and not literal --) and is also used in non-comment contexts like declaring the doctype.

Comment: @Lenoxus The use of `!` was just a side note, but you are right of course. I've updated it little.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if it's a coincidence, but ! is the earliest non-system and non-whitespace character in the ASCII table (at #32). In terms of parsing, would that make it quicker?

No.  And most language design committees would prefer to choose an easy-to-learn, easy-to-remember, and easy-to-type syntax over any minor benefit from having smaller byte values.

Hand-rolled parsers sometimes use lookup-tables to classify tokens based on the first character.  For example, Mozilla's JS engine has the following in `jsscan.cpp` which defines the lexer:

```
static const uint8 firstCharKinds[] = {
/*         0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9    */
/*   0+ */ _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______,   Space,
/*  10+ */     EOL,   Space,   Space,     EOL, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______,
/*  20+ */ _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______, _______,
/*  30+ */ _______, _______,   Space, _______,  String, _______,   Ident, _______, _______,  String,
/*  40+ */ OneChar, OneChar, _______,    Plus, OneChar, _______,     Dot, _______,  HexOct,     Dec,
/*  50+ */     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,     Dec,   Colon, OneChar,
...
```

but using `|` over `!` won't let you make such a table much smaller.  CSS and HTML are heavyweight so memory-constrained devices tend not to parse CSS and saving a few bytes (`'|' - 'z' == 2`) in the lexer is not going to affect browser performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, sorting properties in ASCII order, anything starting with "!" would appear first. My guess is it was just easier to parse this way.

Comment: Easier because `!` is earlier in the ASCII character set you mean? I've added a note about that in the question.

Comment: It may be. I'm just guessing. I did manage to get a classified as to the first on the list in a newspaper once by starting the title with "!", after consulting the ASCII table. :)

Comment: `!important` appears after the property value, not in the property name which is presumably what you would sort by.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because they had to choose something to make it distinguishable from regular CSS code. And it must be before the important because if it was behind, the important could have been read as a value and not a token. But it's rather a guess.

And maybe it is a keyboard layout decision. On german keyboards some tokens are harder to type than on englisch keyboards `{` is a `Alt Gr` `7` for example. `!` is the same on german keyboads as on english ones. Someone maybe had mercy with foreign spoken persons. Again a guess.